# how to compile node-v4.2.4 with armv7 without fpu?

Tags: c++, node.js, arm, fpu

I have a device whose cpu is armv7 but without fpu.

I can compile node with option --with-arm-float-abi=soft, but when I run "node", "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" happened.

```
root@router:/tmp/target/bin# ./node -v    
v4.2.4    
root@router:/tmp/target/bin# ./node --v8-options | head -2    
target arm v7 vfp3 soft    
ARMv7=1 VFP3=1 VFP32DREGS=0 NEON=0 SUDIV=0 UNALIGNED_ACCESSES=1 
MOVW_MOVT_IMMEDIATE_LOADS=0 COHERENT_CACHE=0 USE_EABI_HARDFLOAT=0
```

The tool objdump showed me that there are instructions (such as vpush, vpop...) in use which are not supported by my cpu (arm v7 without fpu).

For the further, I found openssl and v8 in the source of node use fpu's instructions.

the configure line as below

```
./configure \
    --prefix=target \
    --dest-cpu=arm \
    --dest-os=linux \
    --without-snapshot \
    --with-arm-float-abi=soft \
    --fully-static
```

Can somebody tell me how to compile node-v4.2.4 without fpu supported?

source code: [nodejs-v4.2.2](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/node-v4.2.4.tar.gz)

arm version: [Cortex-A9 Floating-Point Unit (FPU)(Optional)](http://www.arm.com/zh/cortex-a9.php)

Answer (score 3):

After many tries, I used node-v0.10.14 instead, which works well without fpu supported. ;-)

So I still do not known how to compile nodejs-v4.2.2 without fpu supported.

Comment: same issue here , I succesfully  disabled vfpu3 by modify config files of v8 sources in node deps dir, by I still got vfpu2 enabled by running `node --v8-options` .   I'm giving up ... use node-v0.10.45 instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.
V8 does not support no fpu mode since 3.18 (https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4447#issuecomment-168549889), the assumption is that the kernel can emulate the FPU for you. And NodeJS is based on V8.

Relavant comment in the source code:
https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/arm/assembler-arm.cc#L174

It's clarified in [v8-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/Z9AOHx6Tiu8/HFSHY5o_CwAJ) too.